# Error in run() method when using Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, runtime-error, runnable, interrupted-exception

I am trying to run an Elevator instance in its own thread. The run() method is being called, but there must be some error in my code that is preventing it from running. My code compiles and runs without errors, but the "Elevator starting up" is never printed.

I think it has to do with Thread.sleep() needing to throw an InterruptedException. I tried to try/catch the exception since Runnable doesn't throw an InterruptedException.

Can you help me figure out why it isn't running?

Here is my run() method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.printf("Elevator starting up");

    while(true) {
        try {
            if (currentDirection == Direction.UP) {
                this.moveUp();
            }
            else if (currentDirection == Direction.DOWN) {
                this.moveDown();
            }
            else {Thread.sleep(250);}
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Elevator has experienced a critical error")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my start() method within the Elevator class. This is called from main for each elevator in the building.

```
public void start() {
    activeThread = new Thread();
    activeThread.start();
}
```

The moveUp() method:

```
public void moveUp() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(travelSpeed);
    setCurrentFloor(currentFloor++);
}
```

The moveDown() method:

```
public void moveDown() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(travelSpeed);
    setCurrentFloor(currentFloor--);
}
```

Full PassengerElevator.class code

```
public class PassengerElevator implements ElevatorMover, Runnable {

private final int elevID;       // elevator number
private final int maxCapacity;  // max capacity of the elevator
private int currentCapacity;    // the current capacity of the elevator
private final long travelSpeed; // length of travel time between floors
private final long doorSpeed;   // length of time door stays open
private int currentFloor;       // the current floor the elevator is on
private final int defaultFloor; // the default floor after timeout
private Direction currentDirection; // the current direction the elevator is moving
public Thread activeThread = null;  // contains the instance of an elevator thread

/**
 * Constructor
 * @param elevID the ID number, as an int, given to the elevator
 */
public PassengerElevator(int elevID) {

    this.elevID = elevID;
    maxCapacity = 10;
    currentCapacity = 0;
    travelSpeed = 500;  // in milliseconds
    doorSpeed = 500;    // in milliseconds
    currentFloor = 1;
    defaultFloor = 1;
    currentDirection = Direction.IDLE;
}

/**
 * makes the elevator go up one floor. Takes travelSpeed time
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
@Override
public void moveUp() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(travelSpeed);
    setCurrentFloor(currentFloor++);
}

/**
 * makes the elevator go down one floor. Takes travelSpeed time
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
@Override
public void moveDown() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(travelSpeed);
    setCurrentFloor(currentFloor--);
}

/**
 * makes the elevator door open for doorSpeed time. When door is open people
 * move into elevator
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
@Override
public void openDoors() throws InterruptedException{
    Thread.sleep(doorSpeed);
}

public int getElevID() {
    return elevID;
}

private int getMaxCapacity() {
    return maxCapacity;
}

private int getCurrentCapacity() {
    return currentCapacity;
}

private void setCurrentCapacity(int x) {
    currentCapacity = x;
}

private double getTravelSpeed() {
    return travelSpeed;
}

private double getDoorSpeed() {
    return doorSpeed;
}

public int getCurrentFloor() {
    return currentFloor;
}

private void setCurrentFloor(int x) {
    currentFloor = x;
}

private int getDefaultFloor() {
    return defaultFloor;
}

private void setCurrentDirection(Direction x) {
    currentDirection = x;
}

private Direction getCurrentDirection() {
    return currentDirection;
}

/**
 * Starts a new thread for an elevator instance to run in
 */
public void start() {
    activeThread = new Thread();
    activeThread.start();
}

/**
 * The running loop for an elevator instance. Client will change current direction
 * and use the currentFloor as a check.
 */
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.printf("Elevator starting up");

    while(true) {
        try {
            if (currentDirection == Direction.UP) {
                this.moveUp();
            }
            else if (currentDirection == Direction.DOWN) {
                this.moveDown();
            }
            else {Thread.sleep(250);}
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Elevator has experienced a critical error")
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Are you saying this doesn't compile?

Comment: @Kon, it compiles, but I'm never getting "Elevator starting up" on my console

Comment: @DavidGrinberg it runs, but I'm never getting "Elevator starting up" on my console

Comment: You're never running your run() method. You start a new Thread but don't schedule anything on it.

Comment: I dont see you ever actually change the direction in your code.

Comment: did you started the thread with `threadname.start();`?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I was under the impression that Thread.start() did that for you.

Comment: @clenard It runs its own run() method which is by default empty. Either have Elevator extends Thread and then do new Elevator(). Or Elevator extends Runnable and do new Thread(new Elevator()).

Comment: @Thecazziator33 Isn't that what my start() method is doing. I thought it was creating a new Thread object and then starting it.

Comment: `activeThread = new Thread();` should most probably be something like `activeThread = new ElevatorThread();` or `activeThread = new Thread(myElevatorRunnable);`

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Do I have to change the direction to make it run? I just want the run method to start running in the infinite loop until I tell the elevator to change direction with my Elevator Control System

Comment: I never see you set the direction in the first place. Can you post the `Elevator` code?

Comment: Where is the run() mehod? With `activeThread = new Thread();` and `activeThread.start();` you are just initializing and starting a new thread... I think we need more code...

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I have added it above

Comment: How do you change direction? you start at idle ... and remain there.

Comment: @TheCazziator33 I have added the full code for PassengerElevator above. My start() and run() are near the bottom.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I am having the elevator sit in an Idle position until my ElevatorController system receives a request from a person and tells the elevator to go Up or Down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `Thread` instance directly, and since it is the plain Java `Thread` class, it has no code in the `run` method. That means that when you start it, it does nothing. This is the relevant code:

```
public void start() {
    activeThread = new Thread();
    activeThread.start();
}
```

You need to start a thread that is going to run your code. Either make your elevator class extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable`.

When extending `Thread`:

```
thread = new Elevator();
thread.start();
```

When implementing `Runnable`:

```
thread = new Thread(new Elevator());
thread.start();
```

The [Thread documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) provides examples of usage.

Comment: This solves my question. Unfortunately, it means I've been barking up the wrong tree. haha. Learning pains.